# Is it cold inside a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, temperature

What is the temperature inside a black hole?

It may be very cold, or very hot.
Or just the surrounding temperature.

Or maybe neither, because the concept of temperature makes no sense inside somehow?

Comment: since time is stopped inside, or at the event horizon, temperature as we know it is meaningless

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476882/25301

Comment: @AdrianHoward: *since time is stopped inside, or at the event horizon,* Not true.

Comment: @AdrianHoward, a clock falling freely towards a black hole 'keeps on ticking' as it falls through the event horizon (oops, Ben beat me to it). Also, comments are not for answers (correct or otherwise).

Comment: @AdrianHoward Wait, the time did what? Stop?

Comment: Temperature is a thermodynamic concept. It measures the average kinetic energy of the random motion of the microscopic constituents of a macroscopic object. As a massive object or a light ray crossing the horizon is doomed to hit the singularity at the center of a black hole, no current physical theory is applicable. Your question has no answer, as for now.

Comment: Oops, had a long answer with references but didn't click submit before it closed. Quick summary: classical vacuum has no temperature, actual universe outside sends in blueshifted radiation that heats objects, semiclassical approach gives Unruh radiation that makes interior warmish.